# How to run function on query results?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query:

```
select a,b,c,d
from x
join y using (id)
join z using (id2)
where....
```

this query gives many rows.
I would like to run `func2(a,b,c,d)` on each row from the query.

I tried:

```
with B as (
    select a,b,c,d
    from x
    join y using (id)
    join z using (id2)
    where....)
select func2(a,b,c,d)
from B
```

but it doesn't work. I'm not sure `WITH` is the right solution.

Comment: try `select func2(a,b,c,d)
    from x
    join y using (id)
    join z using (id2)
    where.`

Comment: I am confused about the answers and the question itself. Because answers dont really differ from questions example - or I am blind. And questions author does not give any info what isnt working, where what kind of result he wants. does func2 return many fields and the query you are using does return set of records and you want that query return fields? if so just use "select (func(a,b,c,d)).* from b"

Comment: the error was syntax error.... The question was very simple... @Kapila Ramji  gave an easier way to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply run the function within the select. This will loop for every row returned. Try it in the following manner:

```
select func2(a,b,c,d)
from x
join y using (id)
join z using (id2)
where....
```

Answer (score 1):

A function can be use within select queries

for example

```
create table t(a int,b int);
insert into t select generate_series(1,5), generate_series(5,5);
```

and If you've a function like below

```
create function fn(val int,val1 int) returns integer
as
$$
select $1+$2;
$$
language sql
```

usage:

```
select fn(1,2)
```

Result:

```
fn 
-- 
3  

(1 row(s) affected)
```

the same way you can use it with the select query

```
select a,b,fn(a,b) 
from t
```

Result:

```
a b fn 
- - -- 
1 5 6  
2 5 7  
3 5 8  
4 5 9  
5 5 10 

(5 row(s) affected)
```

*on the other hand your WITH query should work I guess the problem is something else*

---

See this [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4e0ac/2)